# I got undefined from return function from model.find()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my function that I want to return

```
var setUser = function(Email){
   UserModel.findOne({email : Email}, function(err, data){
      if(err) {
          return Hapi.error.badRequest('There is no this user');
      }
      console.log(data);
      return data;
   });
};
```

The console.log(data); show the result that found. But When I use this function

Example

```
console.log(setUser('123@mail.com'));
```

This log got undefined that returned from function. But log in the function had data.

Answer (score 0):

`.findOne` executes asynchronously and you can't return from the callback function ... that won't go anywhere.  Instead you would need to do something like:

```
setUser('123@mail.com', console.log)

var setUser = function (Email, callback) {
        // .. snip
        callback(data);
}
```

Comment: I want to keep setUser('123@mail.com'); to my var;
Example var data = setUser('123@mail.com');
The var data is undefined.

I don't understand how to use your solution.

Thank a lot guy.

Comment: @SucheepSriintra you need to use callbacks for asynchronous requests in JavaScript / node.  Just do some reading about callbacks.  You even use one in `UserModel.findOne` (the second argument is a callback)